# Issue with permission management in RedHat 8

Tags: bash, redhat

I was practicing questions for RHCSA regarding permissions and i got stuck on an issue.

1. Created directory /data/sales with root #mkdir -p /data/sales
2. Then assigned sales group as group owner of it #chown :sales /data/sales
3. Added pre created user sales1 to sales group   #usermod -aG sales sales1
   others can not create anything inside /data       #chmod -R 770 /data
4. assigned permission to /data/sales #chmod -R 770 /data/sales
5. Now i added sgid on it  #chmod -R 2770 /data/sales
6. Now i created a file and added 1 line inside it whose group owner is sales #vi /data/sales/sales.txt
7. Now i tried to read the file using sales1 user but throwing access denied
   #su - sales1
   #head -n1 /data/sales/sales.txt

Please help me on this. I am not getting why access denied is throwing though sales.txt has sales as group owner as i set SGID on the directory and group has read permission on it.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/data`?

Comment: @Fravadona 770 User root group root

Comment: `chmod 755 /data`

Comment: 2. Configure the permissions so that the user owner (which must be root) and
group owner have full access to the directory. There should be no permissions
assigned to the others entity. Also make sure that “others” will get no
permissions on newly created files and directories within the entire /data
structure.

Comment: I even did the below
#setfacl -dm g:sales:7 /data
But still issue is there

Comment: If `/data` is 770 root:root, then sales1 won't have access to `/data/sales`

Comment: It is working now. i added ACL on /data also 
#setfacl -Rm g:sales:7 /data and it is working

Comment: Please help me to close this question. I got my answer.

Comment: Edit your question and add `[RESOLVED]` at the end of the title